# express-session: alternatives over bundled memorystore

Tags: node.js, mongodb, session, express, express-session

I am looking at implementing express-session into my application and need to make a choice over what session to store to use in place of the bundled memorystore that comes with this library.

I understand the limitations of using memorystore in a production environment, I have seen there are other more stable memory stores such as memcache, which I think I read somewhere can survive app restarts keeping users logged in - have I got that right?

Is there any memory store implementation that can be used in a production environment, or is it advisable to steer clear and go for a proper db store such as mongoDB?

I am trying to minimise the learning curve as much as possible for others in my team and reduce the setup and maintenance overhead for production, which having a separate db store could well bring.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo could be ok, but it might choke under load. YMMV.

Redis is a better bet imho. See https://github.com/tj/connect-redis for example.

Look here for a complete [tutorial](https://codeforgeek.com/2015/07/using-redis-to-handle-session-in-node-js/) using connect-redis